# Suggestions on including audio file(s) in answer

Tags: feature-request

I recently encountered a question about "1000 people whispering" and [wrote an answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/353233/26969). Subsequently I did some experiments where I recorded a whispered sentence 19 times, and did some manipulations to show how this makes the "inaudible" audible.

I would like to update my answer with this work - but don't know of a good way to include audio files in the answer. Does anyone have any good suggestions - or even a recommended mechanism?

The `<audio controls>` HTML5 tag doesn't work... so likely this will be "upload the files somewhere and link". Which is not very satisfying - I hope there's a better solution, especially since there's always the risk that hosting the audio file elsewhere will cause it to go missing in the future.

Comment: [SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/) could be a viable option.

Comment: It is weird that [this has never come up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=audio) until now. It seems a basic question for mother meta, yet no one has asked anything similar as of today. OTOH, from webapps.SE: [Is there a “youtube like” service for audio?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/933). Lots of interesting suggestions there.

Comment: why not just upload to youtube with a dummy image?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform that's a really useful link. Why don't you write this as an answer?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated my answer with files uploaded at archive.org - seems like a really useful resource.

Comment: I'm so happy you asked that here, otherwise I'd not have learned about your wonderful update. I even edited my answer to point to yours instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather surprisingly, I haven't been able to find a similar query neither on this site nor in mother meta. On the other hand, in *Web Applications Stack Exchange* I  found the post [Is there a “youtube like” service for audio?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/933) which contains a lot of interesting suggestions. Please give it a look; I am sure it will prove useful. Cheers.